# Managing multiple stylesheets and .js files when pages are added

Tags: javascript, css

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` in my project.Currently I have five pages in my project , for each page I am having a seperate `Css` file and a `.js` file.For example:For a page `CreateAccount.aspx` I have `CreateAccount.css` and `CreateAccount.js`.My question to you guys is that how do I manage these `stylesheets` and `.js` files when more pages will be added in future , should I persist with my current approach or should I have a single `Css` and `.js` file for my entire project.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The styles and scripts that pages share should be combined into a single script.  Styles and scripts that are unique to an individual page should probably be kept separate.

Comment: but I tend to keep seperate Css file and script file for each page that I add in my project, is that approach ok.thanks

Comment: No it isn't, unless each page is completely unique and even then you'd likely have a common stylesheet.

Comment: @Marko that means I should use fewer Css files and script files or better use only one css file and script file , is it , but dont you think that could be difficult to maintain.

Comment: @freebird Is this for a website that has a general look and feel?

Comment: @Marko no it has many webpages that will have many interaction with the users , that is why my scripts keep getting bigger